# Is the Hadith Sahih "The World is a Prison of the Believer and Paradise for the Kafir" Authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Can anyone please confirm the hadith "The World is a Prison of the Believer and Paradise for the Kafir" is sahih or not. Please give **Reference** and check the conditions of it being sahih. Please take your time and work this out slowly. I want to know whether this is **really Sahih or Not**.

Answer (score 3):

All praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْعَزِيزِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، عَنِ الْعَلاَءِ بْنِ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ الدُّنْيَا سِجْنُ الْمُؤْمِنِ وَجَنَّةُ الْكَافِرِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَفِي الْبَابِ عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَمْرٍو ‏.**‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ صَحِيحٌ ‏.‏**

*"The world is a prison for the believer and Paradise for the disbeliever."* [Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/21) 2324,Chapter 36 on Zuhd

Imam Tirmidhi stated this Hadith as **Sahih**.

It is also mentioned in [Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/55/1) and [Ibn Majah](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1292150).

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 3):

As user **servant** has already pointed out, the hadith is **really Sahih**. The hadith is recorded in Sahih Muslim:

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:

> The world is a prison-house for a believer and Paradise for a non-believer. ([parmalink](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/55/1))

**All hadith in Sahih Muslim (and Sahih Bukhari) are Sahih beyond doubt.**

Read further about his methodology at [about Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/about)

Also read the answer (written for a different question) by user **oshirowanen** to undersatand the meaning of the hadith - [link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/9312/14326).

Comment: Both hadith books, Sahih Muslim and Bukhari were written 240+ years after the death of the Prophet and the average chain contains 5,6,7+ people between the imams and the Prophet. How do you say these works are beyond doubt?